# Visibility widget not hiding when state set

Tags: flutter

I'm having a lot of trouble with visibility being triggered when a user jumps between states. My onboarding widget has a header at the top of the page but when a user navigates to a second route I want it go away and display a full bleed container.

Here's my widget:

```dart
library activate;

import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Step1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Step 1")
  }
}

class Step2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Step 2")
  }
}

class OnboardActivate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  OnboardActivateState createState() => new OnboardActivateState();
}

class OnboardActivateState extends State<OnboardActivate> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _isHeaderVisible = true;
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
      child: Column(children: [
        SafeArea(
          child: Visibility(
            visible: _isHeaderVisible,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 35,
                left: 35,
                right: 35,
                bottom: 15,
              ),
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Step 1 of 4".toUpperCase(),
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .subtitle1
                          .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(children: [
                  Text(
                    "A fun welcome message!",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                  ),
                ]),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35, right: 35, left: 35),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Navigator(
              initialRoute: '/',
              onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                WidgetBuilder builder;
                switch (settings.name) {
                  case '/':
                    builder = (BuildContext _) => Step1();
                    break;
                  case '/step2':
                    builder = (BuildContext _) => Step2();
                    setState(() {
                      _isHeaderVisible = false;
                    });
                    break;
                }
                return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's an example of the UI design itself. The left side is meant to be the state when the `/` root is displayed. The right side is when `/step2` is displayed. I'm using a Navigator for the content inside the UI area and the content outside of it is decorative across all the other routes. After step 1 though I want the header to not be visible. Eventually I'd love to have it animate but for now just sorting out why the Visible widget isn't having an effect is important. I'm thinking maybe I have to trigger a re-render?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_isHeaderVisible` is same even after setting different. Just move it out of `build` method, let it keep last value.

```
class OnboardActivateState extends State<OnboardActivate> {

  bool _isHeaderVisible;

  initState(){
    _isHeaderVisible = true;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //  bool _isHeaderVisible = true; <== REMOVE
    ...
```

Comment: lol wow. Now I feel silly. Sorry new to Dart/Flutter. I just read up on the build method and I'm understanding it a lot better now. This makes way more sense. Thank you.